# DotNet MAUI TableView input collection of items

Tags: xamarin, maui, .net-maui

As per the following documentation, the data for TableView is manually populated with one by one. Is there a way to feed collection and items and set the template for the item.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/tableview

Comment: That would be a ListView with a DataTemplateSelector

Comment: @Json that sucks.  They should have probably mentioned that somewhere on the entire internet besides this one SO post.